# Receiving this error "descriptor 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object" when creating a time object in a discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time, discord.py, pytz

**THE PROBLEM**

Code:

```
@client.command(aliases=["tzc"])
async def timeconvert(ctx, fromtimezone: str, totimezone: str, hour: int, min: int, sec: int):
  inputtime=datetime.time(hour,min,sec)
```

When attempting to execute this (accepting arguments from the user) in discord , python returns the following error:

`descriptor 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object`

**NOTES**

I have more code below, but it isnt the source of the problem and I have omitted them for the sake of simplicty

Here are the time related modules i have imported

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
```

The issue isnt related to discord.py errors

**THE SOLUTION I WANT**

The time object is created successfully. For example if i input the arguments hour, min, sec as 12, 30, 00 respectively , the output should be 12:30:00 when i execute the following statement:

```
print(inputtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Idk if that is what you mean but you can try this:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["tzc"])
async def timeconvert(ctx, hour: int, min: int, sec: int):
    now = datetime.now()
    inputtime = datetime(
        now.year, now.month, now.day, hour=hour, minute=min, second=sec
    )
    print(inputtime)
```

Note that `datetime` object must have year, month and day

Comment: Yeah it was not what i meant, but thanks, this sparked an idea which let me fix it (sort of)